# Error when starting basic react app created with Create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am new to react and am trying to start a basic react webapp following this ["Getting Started"](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started) tutorial.

```
npx create-react-app first_react_app
cd first_react_app
npm start
```

Unfortunately I am getting the following error when starting the app.

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Lernprojekte\React\first_react_app\node_modules\react-dev-utils\WebpackDevServerUtils.js:166
compiler.hooks.done.tap('done', async stats => {
                              ^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:78:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Lernprojekte\React\first_react_app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:45:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
```

I read that async/await is not compatible with some lower versions of node.
I am using node 9.8.0 and npm 6.9.0 in windows 10.
I even deleted the node_modules and npm install again but still getting the same error.

Comment: Please paste the code that you are running

Comment: It is a fresh installation of a basic react app from "create-react-app". I changed nothing on it.

Comment: Well then correct me if I'm wrong, but I see that in the tutorial they say you should write `npm start` and not `npm install`.

Comment: Ah sorry. It s a typo in the question. I have corrected the typo in the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you follow react tutorials([react basic tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started)), you should see quick start commands and try to run these commands.

   npx create-react-app first_react_app
   cd first_react_app
   npm start

and make sure your system has preinstalled npm to start with react.

2. Or you need to update your dev server file to remove this syntax error.

   - go to file in your project **React\first_react_app\node_modules\react-dev-utils\WebpackDevServerUtils.js**
   - go to line no 145 and Update given code.Save this file and restart your server.

> ```
>   compiler.hooks.done.tap('done', stats => {
>     if (isInteractive) {
>       clearConsole();
>     }
> ```

Comment: Ah sorry. It s a typo in the question. I have corrected the typo in the question.

Comment: I think you need to upgrade your npm and node version to latest version.

Comment: I did it with node 10 and npm 6 but i got the same error

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this docs: Try this

```
npm run build
```

then

```
npm run start
```

Comment: When you’re ready to deploy to production, Then you need to run `npm run build` but this issue is related to development server.

Answer (score 0):

i came across the same problem, and although i upgraded npm & node to the latest versions, they were **NOT the most updated in the directory** of the react-app that I created.

solution: go to the directory of your react-app and upgrade npm & node

**nvm install --latest-npm**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your node.js version is outdated. You can update to the latest one or you can configure multiple node.js versions simultaneously. I am using **'n'** a node version manager, so, that I can switch back and forth easily for managing multiple projects. You can read about this in the following link:
[n](https://github.com/tj/n)

You can install it like this:

```
> npm install -g n #install utility globally
> n 10.16.0        #install the version you want
> n                #switch back and forth to node.js versions
```

To know more about the node.js LTS version visit here:
[node-release](https://github.com/nodejs/Release)